# Если каждый элемент в строке равен чему то

Tags: c#

Как перевести следующее условие в код?

> если первый элемент в строке равен "b" или "f" или "a" или "c", то тогда.... 
>   если второй элемент в строке равен "1" или же "6" или же "4" то тогда....

Как именно указать индекс элемента?

Пробовал так, но компилятор не понимает:

```
string stroka;
if(stroka.substring(0,1)=="b"&&=="f")
{
..
}
```

Какая запись будет короче, чтобы не приходилось писать много блоков if?

Comment: Совсем не понятно, что Вам нужно, опишите как-то по подробней или понятней, отформатируйте текст.

Comment: @Ep1demic а что именно вызывает не понимание у Вас ?

Comment: лично у меня вот это: **"прописать 1-й, 2-й элемент итд. в строке И слово "или же", если прописать так типа: string stroka"**

Comment: @Ep1demic я все четко написал, строка str имеет первую букву, 2-ю букву 3-ю букву итд.
или же это типа `&&` или `||`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно так:

```
var first = s.Substring(0, 1);

if (new[] { "a", "b", "c", "f" }.Contains(first))
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Можно вместо *substring* получить по индексу - `s[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть в сторону регулярных выражений, их специально придумали для анализа строк

```
if (new Regex("^[bfac][164]").IsMatch(stroka))
{
}
```

Символ `^` указывает, что искать соответствие надо с начала строки. Выражение `[bfac]` говорит, что ожидается один символ из набора. Далее `[164]` означает что второй по порядку символ должен быть из этого набора. [Понятный мануал на русском можете почитать тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_10.php).

Comment: наборы указаны неверно, что по-твоему входит в набор `[b,f,a,c]`?

Comment: @Grundy да, спасибо, подзабыл)